# Reflection of UIImage without UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

How to create a reflection of UIImage without using UIImageView ? I have seen the apple code for reflection using two imageViews but i don't want to add imageview in my application i just want whole image of the original image and the reflected image. Does any body knows how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from UIImage+FX.m, created by [Nick Lockwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422133/nick-lockwood)

```
UIImage * processedImage = //here your image
processedImage = [processedImage imageWithReflectionWithScale:0.15f
                                                                          gap:10.0f
                                                                        alpha:0.305f];
```

Scale is the size of the reflection, gap the distance between the image and the reflection, and alpha the alpha of the reflection

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithReflectionWithScale:(CGFloat)scale gap:(CGFloat)gap alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    //get reflected image
    UIImage *reflection = [self reflectedImageWithScale:scale];
    CGFloat reflectionOffset = reflection.size.height + gap;

    //create drawing context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height + reflectionOffset * 2.0f), NO, 0.0f);

    //draw reflection
    [reflection drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, reflectionOffset + self.size.height + gap) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];

    //draw image
    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, reflectionOffset)];

    //capture resultant image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return image
    return image;
}
```

and

```
- (UIImage *)reflectedImageWithScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    //get reflection dimensions
    CGFloat height = ceil(self.size.height * scale);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width, height);
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);

    //create drawing context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //clip to gradient
    CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, [[self class] gradientMask]);

    //draw reflected image
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, -self.size.height);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height)];

    //capture resultant image
    UIImage *reflection = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return reflection image
    return reflection;
}
```

gradientMask

```
+ (CGImageRef)gradientMask
{
    static CGImageRef sharedMask = NULL;
    if (sharedMask == NULL)
    {
        //create gradient mask
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, 256), YES, 0.0);
        CGContextRef gradientContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGFloat colors[] = {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
        CGPoint gradientStartPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        CGPoint gradientEndPoint = CGPointMake(0, 256);
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(gradientContext, gradient, gradientStartPoint,
                                    gradientEndPoint, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
        sharedMask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gradientContext);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    return sharedMask;
}
```

it returns the image with the reflection.

Comment: What is [[self class]gradientMask]  ? And what will the above code return? A reflected image or whole (original + reflected) image ?

Comment: added the gradientMask method on the answer. The imageWithReflectionWithScale returns the original+reflected, the reflectedImageWithScale returns just the reflection.

Comment: How to change the height of the reflected image? I want to draw original image as half size of the view and other half should be the reflected image below. Also even if i set alfa value to 1 of reflected image it shows opaque image at the bottom.

Comment: For half size you have to set the reflectionScale to 0.5f. If you don't want the gradient on the reflection image, you can set reflectionAlpha to 1.0f and comment the CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, [[self class] gradientMask]);
 on the reflectedImageWithScale method

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog post awhile ago](http://saveme-dot-txt.blogspot.com/2011/06/dynamic-view-reflection-using.html)  that uses a view's CAReplicatorLayer.  It's really designed for handling dynamics updates to a view with reflection, but I think it would work for what you want to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the image and its reflection inside a graphics context and then get a `CGImage` from the context and from that again a `UIImage`.
But the question is: why not use two views? Why would you think it is a problem or limitation?